# Connection between derivatives and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

I'm studying an example of function: $(x_o-\alpha, x_0+\alpha) \to R$ that have this following properties: 
$f(x)>f(x_0)$   $\forall$ $x \in (x_o, x_o+\alpha)$ 
$f(x)<f(x_o)$ $\forall x \in (x_o-\alpha, x_o)$

but it's not increasing or decreasing definitively in respective interval.
The example is: $$2+x^2\sin\frac{1}{x^4}$$
if $x\neq0$. Otherwise 0 if $x=0$
The author say the problem is the discontinuity of the derivate:
if f' is continuous then we can say that for x>0 we have always $f'>0$. But i dont understand why. I dont understand the link between an increasing derivative and that if is or not continue at some point.
Thank you

Comment: Is there a typo? The example doesn't satisfy the second property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take
$$
f(x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}x+2x^2\sin(1/x^2)& x \neq 0,\\
0, & x=0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
then if $x>0$ one has $f(x)/x= 1+2x\sin(1/x^2)>0$ if $0<|x|<1/2$, since $|x\sin(1/x^2)|\leq |x|$ and so $|2x\sin(1/x^2)|<1$ for $|x| \in (0,1/2)$. It follows that $f(x)>0$ for $x \in (0,1/2)$ and $f(x)<0$ for $x \in (-1/2,0)$ and since $f(0)=0$ by definition it follows that $f$ satisfies the required inequalities with $0=x_0=f(x_0)$ and $\alpha=1/2$.

On the other hand, one has $f'(x) = 1+4x\sin(1/x^2)-2\cos(1/x^2)$ for all $x \neq 0$ and at $x=0$,
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} (1+2h\sin(1/h^2))=1>0
$$
thus $f$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbb R$, and if $f$ was monotonic on an interval containing 0 then as $f'(0)>0$ we would have to have $f$ increasing and $f'(x)\geq 0$ on some interval $(-\delta,\delta)$. However, $f'(x)$ is both positive and negative in any interval $(-\delta, \delta)$ with $\delta<1/8$, since $2\cos(1/x^2)$ will oscillate between $-2$ and $2$ infinitely often in such an interval while $|1+4x\sin(1/x^2)|<1+4\delta=3/2$. It follows that there is no such open interval and hence $f$ is not weakly increasing or weakly decreasing on any open interval containing $0=x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = x + 2 \sin x$.

Is derivative is $f'(x) = 1 + 2 \cos x$ which is continuous, but oscillates between $-1$ and $3$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

However, for $x > 2$ we have $f(x) = x + 2 \sin x > x - 2 > 0$ and for $0 < x < 2$ we have $f(x) = x + 2 \sin x \ge x > 0$. Thus $f(x) > 0 = f(0)$ for $x > 0$, and one can similarly show $f(x) < f(0)$ for $x < 0$.

Comment: You don't answer me